# I cant run ionic serve

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

Can somebody help me? I'm new in ionic. When I try to run serve, this error appears. I ran `sudo npm install -g cordova`, but the error came back.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'xmlbuilder'  
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)  
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)  
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)  
    at require (module.js:380:17)  
    at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:12:13)

at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:436:4)

at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)  
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)  
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)  
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Comment: Check https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8297 this.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing them and reinstalling

```
npm cache clean
npm uninstall -g cordova ionic   
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Use sudo if you are on a mac or a linux.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you're in the project directory? As in assuming you created your app on the desktop, are you sure you're not in C://Users/username/Desktop instead of  C://Users/username/Desktop/myApp ?